# Mismatch of CPU Architecture for the Crosswalk using Cordova

Tags: crosswalk

I have integrate crosswalk plugin in my Cordova application. When I publish this app to google play. I'm not able to open in my Asus gen phone 2 it throws following error

**Error message:Mismatch of CPU Architecture for the Crosswalk**

- Cordova version - 6.0.0
- Crosswalk Version - latest

Can any one help me for resolving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The Asus phones tend to use an Intel x86 chipset. When doing anything with native code, you need to account for the various chipsets used by devices. Crosswalk is built with native code. It sounds like you did not include builds for both the ARM and x86 chipsets to Google play.

The Cordava Crosswalk plugin out-of-the-box will give you 2 chipset builds, 1 for ARM and 1 for x86 CPU architectures. You should be uploading both APK output files to Google Play.

**NOTE**: Since Google play changed the max APK size from 50mb to 100mb, you now have the option of package both chipsets together. However, you may still want to consider having a separate build for each and uploading them separately.

Comment: If someone doesn't know how to upload multiple apk to store, here is the official manual:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html